# EF4 CTP5 one to one mapping with existing database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

So I have an existing database with a Users table and an Airports table each with a primary key names ID.  The Users table has a nullable column DefaultAirportID which is a fk to the ID of the Airports table.

Here are my POCOs:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? DefaultAirportID { get; set; }        
    public Airport DefaultAirport { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Airport : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I keep getting the error "Invalid column name 'AirportID'.".  What do I need to do to get it to populate the DefaultAirport object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use fluent API to configure your association:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.DefaultAirport)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(n => n.DefaultAirportID);        
}
```

Comment: Morteza, thanks for the quick response. That got me one step further. Now I no longer get that exception and the DefaultAirportID is correctly populated but the DefaultAirport is null.

Comment: No problem, if you want it to be lazy loaded, then you need mark it as `virtual`. Otherwise just eager load it with `Include` method.

Comment: Morteza, thank you so much.  You likely saved me a lot of research time.